# Fixing a drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe-fitting

I have a PVC drain pipe which has been snapped off while I was hanging drywall twice.  Major setback to the drywall project, but now I cannot just saw off the offending parts and splice in new PVC.  I need to remove a large section which looks to me like it will include the part that fits into the metal drain pipe that goes into the basement floor.  What is the metal floor pipe called?  How can I attach the new PVC to it properly?  Would it be better to just call a plumber?

[image: Close up profile of the broken pipe]
[image: Left Side]

Comment: I  see the inspection eye is an "outie" m you might want to consider fitting an "innie" (flush plug)  there instead. it will protrude less and thus catch fewer accidental poundings.

Comment: @Jasen I wish I had seen your comment some hours ago.  Basically I already got it back together but I don't even know if I've seen an "innie" at the store... Only the outie ones. I will try to remember this next time I have this problem (which is hopefully never again, lol).

Comment: it's just the removable part you need to replace.  eg: https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/4-dwv-pvc-cleanout-plug-flush-d110-040.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to fix it myself if I were you. It's a drain pipe so not under a lot of pressure. Cut away the part that's broken and then see if you can pry, snap, grind off the rest of the female sleeve eposing the nipple that goes into that small section of PVC. Then build up from there.

If that doesn't work, try breaking out the nipple from the small section of PVC, add a new nipple and build up from there.

You could also carefully cut the small PVC piece right at the bottom of the coupling. There appears to be enough straight PVC remaining to add another coupling and build up from there.

Last but not least, cut and pry out that small piece of PVC from the cast iron pipe. It looks like it was sealed in there with some type of flexible seal, foam or expoy putty. You should be able to break it out and clean up the threads, get a reducer fitting or epoxy putty and start over.

Comment: I think this is the answer to what my original problem was.  But I discovered that parts of this were never glued together in the first place.  So I was able to get away with just cutting the tributary pipes and pulling the rest of it out.  Maybe I could have saved more of the old fittings if I had known about the heat trick.  I guess I thought I read before you're not supposed to reuse fittings that have been heated in order to be separated.

Answer (score 1):

if you heat the socket parts with a heat gun or propane torch they can often be slit with a knife and then peeled off the pipe.

so saw out the bulk of the broken part and then use heat to soften the remainder so that it can be removed too.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work getting it back together if I just took the inspection piece out and tried to glue a new one in because it's such a tight fit.  But I got it back together anyway after having to make several trips to the store.